# Dagger: IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am new to Dagger 2. I have 2 Activities, I want to use injected ViewModel for both. Here is my **ViewModuleFactory** :

```
@Singleton
public class ProductViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    public ProductViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        this.creators = creators;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown viewmodel class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My **ViewModelModule**:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ProductListViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindProductListViewModel(ProductListViewModel listViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ProductDetailsViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindProductDetailsViewModel(ProductDetailsViewModel detailsViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ProductViewModelFactory factory);
}
```

My **ViewModelKey** for mapping:

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

My **ActivityModule** :

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {
    abstract ProductListActivity contributeProductListActivity();
    abstract ProductDetailsActivity contributeProductDetailsActivity();
}
```

My **AppModule**:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

@Provides
    @Singleton
    RedMartProductService provideRedMartProductService() {
        ........
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ProductListRepository provideProductListRepository(ProductListRepository repository) {
        return repository;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ProductDetailsRepository provideProductDetailsRepository(ProductDetailsRepository repository) {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

My **AppComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, ActivityModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MartApplication martApp);
}
```

My **Application**:

```
public class MartApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

In **Activity**:

```
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
.......
AndroidInjection.inject(activity); // Throwing exception
ListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ProductListViewModel.class);
```

It is throwing an exception on inject:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.mymart.ui.ProductListActivity>
```

Can anyone help me identify the problem in my code?

.......................................................................

**Edit**: I tried with `ContributesAndroidInjector` as per @azizbekian, but it resulted following error on build:

```
    error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] Found a dependency cycle:
com.mymart.repository.ProductListRepository is injected at
com.mymart.di.AppModule.provideProductListRepository(repository)
com.mymart.repository.ProductListRepository is injected at
com.mymart.viewmodel.ProductListViewModel.<init>(productListRepository)
com.mymart.viewmodel.ProductListViewModel is injected at
com.mymart.di.ViewModelModule.bindProductListViewModel(listViewModel)
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
com.mymart.viewmodel.ProductViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
com.mymart.viewmodel.ProductViewModelFactory is injected at
com.mymart.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
com.mymart.ui.ProductListActivity.viewModelFactory
com.mymart.ui.ProductListActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

**Edit 2**
After all changes, I am facing again exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.kaushik.myredmart.MartApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.kaushik.myredmart.di.AppModule must be set
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.kaushik.myredmart.di.AppModule must be set
                                                 at com.kaushik.myredmart.di.DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java:180)
                                                 at com.kaushik.myredmart.di.AppInjector.init(AppInjector.java:30)
                                                 at com.kaushik.myredmart.MartApplication.onCreate(MartApplication.java:28)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I believe you have forgot to put `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation:

```
    @Module
    public abstract class ActivityModule {
        @ContributesAndroidInjector
        abstract ProductListActivity contributeProductListActivity();
        @ContributesAndroidInjector
        abstract ProductDetailsActivity contributeProductDetailsActivity();
    }
```

And include `ViewModelModule` within `AppModule`:

```
    @Module(includes = ViewModelModule.class)
    class AppModule {
        ...
    }
```

---

See this code that you have wrote:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ProductListRepository provideProductListRepository(ProductListRepository repository) {
    return repository;
}
```

What do you expect to happen? You are telling dagger *"hey, dagger, whenever I ask you to provide me `ProductListRepository` then create(return) that object using `ProductListRepository`"*. That's not gonna work out.

Most possibly what you intended was *"hey, dagger, whenever I ask you to provide me an implementation of `ProductListRepository` then create(return) that object using `ProductListRepositoryImpl`"*:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ProductListRepository provideProductListRepository(ProductListRepositoryImpl repository) {
    return repository;
}
```

Which may be substituted with following:

```
@Binds
@Singleton
abstract ProductListRepository provideProductListRepository(ProductListRepositoryImpl repository);
```

Comment: I tried. Please check my edited part above and guide.

Comment: I followed you, it resulted a dependency cycle. Please advise.

Comment: Added above in the edited part. Please check @azizbekian

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Dependency problem solved, but giving exception on run : Unable to create application com.mymart.MartApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.mymart.di.AppModule must be set

Comment: See some tutorial. You had plenty of issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation

Answer (score 4):

For this error: "**Dagger: IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class**"

If you are using **Navigation Component** with **Single Activity**, you can see this error.

> What should you do?
>
> Please check your ***@Module abstract class FragmentProvider { ... }*** because you need to add your Fragment inside of it as Contribute.

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentProvider {

  @ContributesAndroidInjector // <- Do not forget this line.
  abstract fun contributeYourNewFragment(): YourNewFragment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dagger2 Errors are more straightforward than dagger1 but it popup one by one depending on what issue dagger face in compilation time first.

You faced more than the error above with your solutions :

- 1st Error : Dagger: IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

and that's because of you provide dagger with activity in the ActivityModule without adding the annotation @ContributesAndroidInjector

This annotation must be applied to an abstract method in a Module that returns a concrete Android framework type.” i.e. Activity / Fragment, etc.

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ProductListActivity contributeProductListActivity();
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ProductDetailsActivity contributeProductDetailsActivity();
}
```

[Ref](https://dagger.dev/api/2.13/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html)

- 2nd Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppModule must be set
  at DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java:180)

If Your AppModule doesn't have any default constructor so Dagger can't create an instance of AppModule. so create an AppModule instance and set it to Dagger graph.

```
 mComponent = DaggerXComponent.builder()
    .appModule(new AppModule(....)) // create appModule instance
    .build();
```

If modules don't have any user defined constructor then Dagger will automatically create an instance via default constructor when required.

Find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967798/8713823)

Answer (score 0):

You may see this when using Java keywords, like `new` or `short`, `long`, etc., in your package names (even if you are using Kotlin throughout your app).

Dagger generates Java code for your definition and classes. This code generation will fail for package names equal to reserved Java keywords. For instance, if you have a package `your.app.com.paywall.new.ui`, code generation will silently fail to generate the necessary Dagger classes and methods. This is, why you will only see this exception during runtime.

Answer (score -22):

Using the @contrubutesAndroidInjector requires an additional annotationProcessor.

Add this line to your gradle build file:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
```