# Dagger Module must be set

Tags: android, dagger-2

I was trying to add Dagger2. However, I am not able to figure out this compilation error: `MainActivityModule must be set` which happens in my `MainActivity`. If someone will try to throw some light on this error. I would really be glad.

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Inject
JsonMethods mJsonMethods;
...
in OnCreate
Weather.getComponent().injectMainActivity(this);
```

**My Weather class**

```
public class Weather extends Application {

private static WeatherComponent sWeatherComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sWeatherComponent = DaggerWeatherComponent.builder()
            .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
            .build();
}

public static WeatherComponent getComponent() {
    return sWeatherComponent;
}
}
```

**WeatherComponent**

```
@Component(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
public interface WeatherComponent {
    void injectMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**MainAcitivtyModule**

```
@Module(includes = NetworkModule.class)
public class MainActivityModule {

private final MainActivity mainActivity;

public MainActivityModule(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@Provides
@WeatherApplicationScope
public JsonMethods provideJsonMethods(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return new JsonMethods(mainActivity, retrofit);
}
```

NetworkModule return `Retrofit`, `Gson`, `OkHttpClient`

Error `MainActivityModule must be set` appears in this code:

```
sWeatherComponent = DaggerWeatherComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .build();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create a `MainActivityModule` instance like you created `ContextModule` instance. Your `MainActivityModule` don't have any default constructor so `Dagger` can't created an instance of `MainActivityModule`. So create an `MainActivityModule` instance and set it to `Dagger` graph.

```
    sWeatherComponent = DaggerWeatherComponent.builder()
        .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
        .mainActivityModule(new MainActivityModule(....))
        .build();
```

If modules don't have any user defined constructor then `Dagger` will automatically create an instance via default constructor when required.

Comment: Thank you very much. Save my day))

Comment: Welcome :)  :)  :)